# Calling external REST Api

Tags: angular

I am calling external rest API from my Angular2 application, and I receive this error in a response:

```
Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Is there anything I can do about it when I don't have a control over the server?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    this._http.get('https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/wojewodztwa')
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(
            success=>{
                console.log(success);
            }
        )
```

When I am trying to make GET method on this endopint in POSTMAN, it works fine. In Chrome, it throws the above error.

This seems to be Chrome only issue - it works on Safari and Firefox.

It works fine when I am using jQuery to get the response:

```
 $.get("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/wojewodztwa", function(data){
      console.log(data);
  })
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're trying to do? What HTTP method you're calling, what browser is showing you the issue, everything that you've tried, the Access-Control-* headers from the server etc?

Comment: Well, if the server responds, that this token is not allowed and you have no access to the server, then you can't really do anything ...

Comment: @rinukkusu, It seems to be chrome only issue though

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you have some sort of http interceptor which adds `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to all your (get?) http requests. I just tested it, if I don't add anything to my request header, this works like a charm:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/wojewodztwa')
        .map(response => response = response.json());
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

But, if I add anything to header request, I get the same error as you. For example, I just added header with name `Something` and value `Something`:

```
headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Something': 'Something' });

getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/wojewodztwa', {
        headers: this.headers
    })
        .map(response => response = response.json());
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

This will produce the error you are getting:

> Request header field something is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Just to be clear, I tested this in Chrome.